# How to query and get maximum value from function

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to make a query which will get a record with the lowest metric, calculate based on model's fields: view, unique_views and some other parameter, which is constant for the query.

My guess was to use

```
session.query(func.min(get_metric(Post.views, Post.unique_views, 6))).first()
```

But I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/posts/testing.py", line 32, in <module>
    session.query(func.min(get_metric(Post.views, Post.unique_views, 6))).first()
  File "/home/john/PycharmProjects/posts/testing.py", line 19, in get_metric
    metric = radians(views) + cos(unique_views) + asin(weight)
TypeError: must be real number, not InstrumentedAttribute
```

Model

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    views = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    unique_views = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

function

```
def get_metric(views, unique_views, weight):
    metric = radians(views) + cos(unique_views) + asin(weight)
    return metric
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Python's mathematical functions work with numbers, not SQLAlchemy constructs. In order to produce the SQL expression you need to use `func` to create the SQL function expressions. You can use your existing function by modifying it to accept the namespace it uses for math as an argument:

```
import math

def get_metric(views, unique_views, weight, math=math):
    metric = math.radians(views) + math.cos(unique_views) + math.asin(weight)
    return metric
```

Now when you want to produce SQL, pass `func` as math:

```
session.query(func.min(get_metric(Post.views, Post.unique_views, 6, math=func))).first()
```

Comment: Note that this works because many mathematical functions in postgresql have names that overlap with the ones in the `math` module. Some functions do not, however: `CBRT` has no equivalent, `CEILING` has `.ceil`, `POWER` has `.pow`… I like the dependency injection though, it is a clean approach.